# Calculate a subscription end date from the set of date, interval, and period using mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to calculate the expiry date from the set of date, interval number, and period (day, week, month, and year).

Here is my data

[image]

Expecting expiry date is `2020-09-24` based on calculation below

`((2020-01-22)+8 months)+((2020-01-22)+2 days) = 2020-09-24`

I tried with below select query but its not showing expecting output,

```
SELECT CASE t.cycle_period
   WHEN "day" THEN DATE_ADD(t.createdTime, INTERVAL t.cycle_number DAY)
   WHEN "week" THEN DATE_ADD(t.createdTime, INTERVAL t.cycle_number WEEK)
   WHEN "month" THEN DATE_ADD(t.createdTime, INTERVAL t.cycle_number MONTH)
   WHEN "year" THEN DATE_ADD(t.createdTime, INTERVAL t.cycle_number YEAR)
   END
   AS expiry, t.cycle_period FROM (
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(createdTime,'%Y-%m-%d') AS createdTime,SUM(cycle_number) AS cycle_number, 
   cycle_period FROM subscriptions 
   WHERE STATUS='COMPLETED' AND user_id='2' 
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(createdTime,'%Y-%m-%d'),cycle_period
   ORDER BY createdTime DESC) t
```

Any help please!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT createdTime, 
       createdTime
     + INTERVAL COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN cycle_period = 'YEAR' THEN cycle_number END), 0) YEAR
     + INTERVAL COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN cycle_period = 'MONTH' THEN cycle_number END), 0) MONTH
     + INTERVAL COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN cycle_period = 'WEEK' THEN cycle_number END), 0) WEEK
     + INTERVAL COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN cycle_period = 'DAY' THEN cycle_number END), 0) DAY
     AS expiry
FROM subscriptions 
GROUP BY createdTime;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=70f314a1db1e8d5cb49f29cf6f186f78)